# Reproducing error by knowing URL used by user - Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I have several places in my code which cause errors. 
Usually it is

> Call to a member function functionDefined_in_Model() on null at /var/www/myappname/app/Http/Controllers/PerceptsController.php:1298)

In the code I have this:

```
public function report_on_entity($id, $pivoted = 'alpha') {
$object = Entity::find($id);
$standpoints = $object->functionDefined_in_Model()->paginate(10);
```

This code produces `Call to a member function functionDefined_in_Model() on null` which is impossible as far as I know as the URL is defined only by existing Entity models.

### What I need

Is that possible to get an error feedback with the URL which was hit by my user?

Comment: Does functionDefined_in_Model exists?

Comment: It does exist. It works in other cases. So that is not the problem. I guess there is an inconsistency in my DB. So ability to see which URL caused the error solves this and many more problems of mine.

Comment: It means exactly what it means. You are making a call from a null pointer. That means, in your context, that $object is coming "null". You either have to verify $object before making use of it, or take a look why Entity::find($id) is bringing null.

Comment: I just solved my problem. Ability to see URL helped me to discover, that in one or generated URLs I have reversed Model ID with text parameter. and that was the reason that `$object` was null. This case proves that ability to see url in debug information is extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

I made a clever solution and got what I wanted by this:

```
if(!$object) {
     $error_at_URL = url()->current();
        Mail::raw($message, function ($message_content) use ($id, $error_at_URL) {
     $message_content->to('youremail@domain.com');

     $message_content->subject('Error triggered by Entity id '.$id.' at this url: '.$error_at_URL. ". ");
     });
}
```

Of course I could store the responses in DB, but the above trick does the job.